# Return rows even if record does not exist LEFT join with group by clause

Tags: mysql, database

i have two tables

table_lead

```
customer_id  created_on             rating_id
1889         2015-02-26 06:24:54    2
1890         2015-03-02 11:27:16    3
1892         2015-03-03 08:19:30    2
1899         2015-03-09 10:56:24    2
1902         2015-03-10 07:21:40    2
1904         2015-03-20 07:28:05    2
1908         2015-04-01 12:34:47    4
1909         2015-04-06 03:29:26    4
1922         2015-04-27 07:00:36    3
1926         2015-04-29 10:31:06    2
1929         2015-05-01 11:59:08    1
1931         2015-05-05 08:49:38    1
1933         2015-05-05 08:56:17    1
1939         2015-05-05 10:29:45    1
1940         2015-05-05 10:36:20    1
```

table_ratings

```
rating_id   rating
1           Cold
2           Warm
3           Hot
4           Lost
```

I want to get count of all the leads based on rating for all the months of a year that are in rating table for this I am using following query

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.rating_id),MONTHNAME(t1.created_on),t2.rating,t1.rating_id FROM customer_detail t1
RIGHT JOIN master_lead_rating t2 ON t1.rating_id = t2.rating_id 
WHERE t1.is_lead = 1 AND YEAR(t1.created_on) =2015 GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(t1.created_on, '%Y-%m'),t2.rating_id
```

but the result of this query is

```
COUNT(t2.rating_id) MONTHNAME(t1.created_on)    rating  rating_id
1                   February                    Warm    2
4                   March                       Warm    2
1                   March                       Hot     3
1                   April                       Warm    2
1                   April                       Hot     3
1                   April                       Lost    4
5                   May                         Cold    1
```

I want to show count for ratings null or 0 if not exist like in February there should come rows for Hot/Lost/Cold with count as 0 or null.. How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14f57/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this table;

```
create table `cal` (
    `id` int,
    `cal_name` varchar (60)
); 

insert into `cal` (`id`, `cal_name`) values ('1', 'January'),('2', 'February'),('3', 'March'),('4', 'April'),('5', 'May'),('6', 'June'),('7', 'July'),('8', 'August'),('9', 'September'),('10', 'October'),('11', 'November'),('12', 'December');
```

then perform this query;

```
select cal.cal_name, count(rating_id), master_lead_rating.rating, master_lead_rating.rating_id
from cal
left join customer_detail on month(customer_detail.created_on) = cal.id
left join master_lead_rating on master_lead_rating.rating_id = customer_detail.rating_id
group by id
```

99% sure it works, sqlfiddle died on me before i finished testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(c.rating_id)
     , MONTHNAME(c.created_on)
     , r.rating
     , r.rating_id 
  FROM ratings r
  LEFT 
  JOIN customer_detail c
    ON c.rating_id = r.rating_id 
   AND c.is_lead = 1 
   AND c.created_on BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' 
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(c.created_on, '%Y-%m')
     , r.rating_id;
```

Comment: In that case provide a sqlfiddle and a desired result.

Comment: See my previous comment

Comment: See my previous comment